# Materialist Epistemology?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, consciousness

In a normal theory of knowledge, a person's phenomenal consciousness is taken as basic. Thus, the sciences are an attempt at explaining the "world" that affects phenomenal consciousness. Excising phenomenal consciousness, everything disappears. How do materialists get around this nil? What objections are there to their work-around? Is this another case where those believing in phenomenal consciousness and those that don't talk past each other?

Comment: You can see : Robert Koons & George Bealer (editors), *The Waning of Materialism* (2010) and Galen Strawson, *Real Materialism and Other Essays* (2008).

Comment: Materialism does not require "excising phenomenal consciousness" -- consciousness occurs, it just happens to be a characteristic of some types of material processes.

Comment: You might think about what you mean by “normal theory of knowledge.” Are you including reliabilism and other externalist theories which are very popular in epistemology? I am not convinced, without some argument, that they take phenomenal consciousness as basic.